# Matrix related Problems

Tags: matrices

[image]Question:

Hi i am writing a solution of an example of matrix. In which I facing some problems.

- My first problem is how to increase space before and after vertical lines (which separate two matrices)
- and second issue is the `text Operating R_{12}`, I wish to write between two steps.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\x{\times}
\newcommand\y{\cellcolor{green!10}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{parskip}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.10}
\newenvironment{rowequmat}[1]{\left[\array{@{}#1@{}}}{\endarray\right]}
\begin{document}
    \large
    \begin{flalign*}
    [A \mid I] &=\begin{rowequmat}{cc|cc}
    1  &  2 & 1 & 0 \\
    3  &  4 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{rowequmat}&\\[12pt]
    \text{Operating}\;\; R_{12} &\sim\begin{rowequmat}{cc|cc}
    3  &  4 & 0 & 1 \\
    1  &  2 & 1 & 0 \\
    \end{rowequmat}&\\[12pt]
    &\sim\begin{rowequmat}{cc|cc}
    1  &  2 & 0 & 0 \\
    1  &  0 & 1 & 5 \\
    \end{rowequmat}&\\[12pt]
    \end{flalign*}  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, 
            amssymb}
%\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcommand\x{\times}
\newcommand\y{\cellcolor{green!10}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.10}
\newenvironment{rowequmat}[1]{\left[\array{@{}#1@{}}}{\endarray\right]}

\begin{document}
    \large
    \setlength\arraycolsep{3pt}
    \begin{flalign*}
    [A \mid I] &=\begin{rowequmat}{cc|cc}
    1  &  2 & 1 & 0 \\
    3  &  4 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{rowequmat} &   \\
\intertext{Operating $R_{12}$}
    &\sim\begin{rowequmat}{cc|cc}
    3  &  4 & 0 & 1 \\
    1  &  2 & 1 & 0 \\
    \end{rowequmat}&    \\[6pt]
    &\sim\begin{rowequmat}{cc|cc}
    1  &  2 & 0 & 0 \\
    1  &  0 & 1 & 5 \\
    \end{rowequmat}&    
    \end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wonderful Thanks a lot sir for this great help.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `@{}` to change the spacing between any pair of columns (see the first matrix in the code below).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\x{\times}
\newcommand\y{\cellcolor{green!10}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{parskip}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.10}
\newenvironment{rowequmat}[1]{\left[\array{@{}#1@{}}}{\endarray\right]}
\begin{document}
    \large
    \begin{flalign*}
    [A \mid I] &=\begin{rowequmat}{cc@{\ \ }|@{\ \ }cc}
    1  &  2 & 1 & 0 \\
    3  &  4 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{rowequmat}&\\[12pt]
    \text{Operating $R_{12}$} &\sim\begin{rowequmat}{cc|cc} % Writing text this way is more readable
    3  &  4 & 0 & 1 \\
    1  &  2 & 1 & 0 \\
    \end{rowequmat}&\\[12pt]
    &\sim\begin{rowequmat}{cc|cc}
    1  &  2 & 0 & 0 \\
    1  &  0 & 1 & 5 \\
    \end{rowequmat}&\\[12pt]
    \end{flalign*}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't understand your second question.

Comment: Actually i want to write that text (Operating...) between two steps of solution it means exactly between 1st and 2nd steps.

Comment: @Maths4Sandy Could you please illustrate what you need by a simple sketch?

Comment: i added desirable output image in question

Comment: see if inserting `\intertext` between first in second matrices is what you looking for:

Comment: I hope you will understand my question now.

Comment: @Maths4Sandy Sorry for being out for a while. For that, see Zarko’s answer.

Comment: Also Thanks to Fractal for help

Comment: ok have an upvote and a bookmark for the @{} directive... i usually face similar problems and solve them by just inserting as many blank columns as neccesary to make the output look appealing....